# SAS: Issue with importing text parameter file using input statement

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm importing a parameter file in txt form with no title row such as the following:

```
byvars             TEST16X GIO
log_transform      N
y_intercept        Y
exclude_outliers   N
exclude_einmos     N
```

Because it is a parameter file, the length of the two columns will not be fixed. The following is the problematic code I created to import the txt file. The two columns are concatenated instead of splitting into individual columns:

```
data test1;
    infile "files/parameters.txt" DELIMITER='09'x col=Colpoint
    length=linelen;
    length pname $30 pvalue $10;

    input @1 pname $ @;
    varlen=linelen - colpoint + 1;
    input pvalue $varying1024. varlen;
    call symputx('pname', STRIP(pvalue));
run;
```

Output:
[image]

This parameter file defines global macro variables and their values. Such that log_transform is a macro variable with value 'N'.

Comment: will the first parameter always be a single word?

Comment: So the goal is to read in the text file into a dataset?  or are you only interested in making the macro variables.

Comment: Your first variable will be limited to 32 chars as that's a SAS limitation. In both posts (here and on communities.sas.com) the delimiter is not a tab, but we'll assume that is the delimiter in your actual text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be working way too hard. Just use TRUNCOVER and formatted input for the PVALUE field.  Use list mode input for the parameter name field.

```
data parameters;
  infile "files/parameters.txt" truncover ;
  input pname :$32. pvalue $200. ;
  call symputx(pname,pvalue);
run;
```